# Should we put the script or the template first in a single file component for productivity?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am wondering what would be the most efficient way to code in a single file component. I am only talking about productivity as there is no rule regarding how to organize them. [As stated in the style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Single-file-component-top-level-element-order-recommended):

> Single-file components should always order template, script, and style tags consistently, with  last, because at least one of the other two is always necessary.

I usually put the template first as it seems quicker to understand what the component does at first sight.

But at the same time, we spend most of our time writing logic inside the script tags and having the props at the top is kind of appealing.

Also, one could argue that putting the template and the style next to each other makes things easier when we style components. Sometimes you may have to scroll the whole script tags to get to the right css class.

What order do you use for productivity and why?

Comment: you'd be better off asking this kind of thing on a forum

Comment: You're right, that's what I did: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/should-we-put-the-script-or-the-template-first-in-a-single-file-component-for-productivity/20945

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use the default template, script, style order. As it is the one most commonly used it's the one other developers are familiar with and thus it makes collaborating with other people easier. I personally find it a bit weird that the style guide doesn't recommend this order as a recommended one.

It is true that you might be working with template and style or template and script simultaneously so in that sense having template in the middle would make sense. In the editor that I use, which is VS Code, you can collapse only the template block and not the script and style blocks. However inside the script block, with VS Code you can collapse the export default part, which contains most of the component logic, so it lets me work easier with the template and style simultaneously.

Still I believe that deviating from the standard albeit not recommended by the style guide order is the best way, however depending on your editor and which blocks you are able to collapse other orders might make sense as well.